# Different resul in spreadsheet and direct input, possibly due to .specialcells(xlCellTypeBlank)?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have some VBA UDFs which do some Basic stuff, like finding the complement of a range from anouther range etc. One UDF Returns a culled range, that is, takes one range and Returns the range that are not empty. In direct Input this work fine. If I enter this in Excel direktly, I get a value error. I traced the bug down to the complementing function of the empty cells. If in direct Input, the empty cells are properly identified and removed. From spreadsheet, the entire range is considered empty and is therefore removed.

```
Steps to reproduce:
1. Type 5 different values in cells A1:A5, leave A6 blank.
2. Add the UDFs below to your static module.
3. In some other cell than A1:A6 type "=hrIsAllUnique(A1:A5)" or "=hrIsAllUnique(A1:A6)". Both yield a value error.
4. In direct Input enter "?hrIsAllUnique(Range("Data!A1:A6"))
```

There's some Debugging code contained. As you can see from it, in the direct Input case, A6 is properly sliced of. In the spreadsheet Version, A1:A5 (or A1:A6) is removed, which of course is nonsense.

```
Public Function hrCullRange(r As Range) As Range
    If Not hrIsCalced(r) Then Exit Function
    Dim rBlank      As Range
    Set rBlank = Nothing
    On Error GoTo hell
    Set rBlank = r.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Debug.Print ("Removing blank cells: " & rBlank.Address)
    Set hrCullRange = hrComplement(r, rBlank)
    Exit Function
hell:
    ' Nothing to cull
    Set hrCullRange = r
End Function

Public Function hrComplement(outer As Range, inner As Range) As Range
    Dim c          As Range
    Dim t          As Integer
    Set hrComplement = Nothing
    For Each c In outer
        If Intersect(c, inner) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print ("c is part of the complement of inner: " & c.Address)
            If hrComplement Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print ("Adding first cell.")
                Set hrComplement = c
            Else
                Set hrComplement = Application.Union(hrComplement, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Function

Public Function hrIsAllUnique(r As Range, Optional ignoreEmpty As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    If Not hrIsCalced(r) Then Exit Function
    Dim x   As Range
    Dim u   As Long
    If ignoreEmpty Then
        Set x = hrCullRange(r)
    Else
        Set x = r
    End If
    If x.Count = 0 Then
        hrIsAllUnique = True
    Else
        hrIsAllUnique = (x.Count = hrCountUnique(x))
    End If
End Function
Public Function hrCountUnique(target As Range) As Long
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim x   As Variant
    v = target.Value2
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each x In v
        col.Add x, x
    Next x
    On Error GoTo 0
    hrCountUnique = col.Count
End Function
```

Do not try to solve the question, if the values are unique. The UDFs presented are all part of a larger library and must work in different contexts. So the culling function and the complement function Need to work flawless independet of the particular use. I only included the extra layer of hrIsAllUnique, because in spreadsheets, it is a hassle to work with functions returning ranges.

I have a strong suspicion that specialcells is the source of the issue.

An ideal solution would ensure that hrCullRange does exactly what the headline says - returning the range without empty cells.

Comment: You are correct: you cannot use `Specialcells` in a UDF called from a cell.

Comment: @Rory Ah. Ok, that confirms my suspicion. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: I'd probably just load the cell formulas into an array, loop through that checking for zero length, and build up a range from that, using `Union`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Rory, who pointed out in a comment, that, yes indeed, specialcells does not work within the context of a UDF called from a cell.